# 2nd gen package profiles issue

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, profile, package-install, second-generation-packaging

I stuck with issue with choosing custom profiles when 2nd gen package is installed.
Package provides only **'No Access'** and **'Full Access'** settings, but in my project there are some custom profiles which I would like to choice.[image: custom profile choice]

When I have created package the metadata is

```
{
  "destinationProfiles": [
    {
      "description": "Full Access (Your profile must have full access to the package)",
      "displayname": "System Administrator",
      "name": " PT1",
      "noAccess": false,
      "profileId": "profileId",
      "type": "Admin"
    },
    {///All standard profiles from DEV HUB org}
  ],
  "sourceProfiles": [
    {
      "label": "No Access",
      "value": "__noAccess__"
    },
    {
      "label": "Full Access",
      "value": "__allAccess__"
    }
  ]
}
```

> But 2-3 days ago I had another package metadata with the same profiles in project:

````
```{
  "destinationProfiles": [
    {
      "description": "Full Access (Your profile must have full access to the package)",
      "displayname": "System Administrator",
      "name": " PT1",
      "noAccess": false,
      "profileId": "profileId",
      "type": "Admin"
    },
{///All standard profiles from DEV HUB org}
  ],
  "sourceProfiles": [
    {
      "label": "No Access",
      "value": "__noAccess__"
    },
    {
      "label": "Full Access",
      "value": "__allAccess__"
    },
    {
      "label": "Custom Profile 1",
      "value": "Custom Profile 1"
    },
    {
      "label": "Custom Profile 2",
      "value": "Custom Profile 2"
    },
    {
      "label": "Custom Profile 3",
      "value": "Custom Profile 3"
    },
    {
      "label": "Custom Profile N",
      "value": "Custom Profile N"
    }
  ]
}
````

And when I installed the package I could choose settings for appropriate profile.

I used `sf package version create -d force-app -x -w 30` command to create package version.
There was no changes on my DEV HUB org (or there was but as I could see they did not affect packaging).

**Mystery...**

Can anyone help to resolve issue? Any thoughts are welcome :)

Comment: I don't have the answer, but why not delivering Permission Sets with your package, then assign users to them ?

Comment: @NicolasVuillamy, thanks for your curiosity) My answer is because of earlier errorы in application architecture. So now we should leave it as is.

Answer (score 2):

After a millions and billions of investigation hours I found that `"includeProfileUserLicenses": true` attribute from `packageDirectories` in my `sfdx-project.json` file was accidentally deleted in one of previous merges.

Adding this attribute helped fixing the issue and all custom profiles appeared in package.